# Shorcut to pan in Preview?

Tags: keyboard, preview

Is there a shortcut (or the ability to assign one) to pan in Preview app?

It is quite troublesome to keep moving the mouse to and fro the scrollbars when we want to scroll.

Answer (score 5):

If "Rectangular Selection" is selected under Tools (not Automatic Selection nor Text Selection), then you can use <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to temporarily enable the hand tool and then drag the document around to pan.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your mousewheel to pan up and down. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + mouse-wheel to pan left and right.

I just found that it may be easier to use Quick Look for the feature you're after. In finder, select your file and press the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to open it in Quick Look. Then if you use <kbd>command</kbd>+ you can zoom in.  Then you can click and drag to pan.

Use <kbd>command</kbd>- to zoom out, and <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> or <kbd>esc</kbd> to exit.

Answer (score 1):

In `Preview` the arrow keys on the keyboard will scroll up, down, left and right when you have any document open. <kbd>command</kbd>+ and <kbd>command</kbd>- will zoom in and out.